# How to document swagger specification which returns ResponseEntity<Resource> where Resource is org.springframework.core.io.Resource

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have a rest end point which returns `ResponseEntity<Resource>`.
Need to check how can I create this type of response in Swagger specification. 
Here Resource from package is `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`

```
@GetMapping("/downloadZip/{cycleId}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downLoadDATFileAsZip(@RequestParam(value ="cycleId", required = false)  String cycleId) {
     //generating zip file and returning as 
     return responseEntity;
}
```

Here is the part of my swagger specs file.  I need to know how to document its schema type in type section

```
"/downloadZip/{cycleId}" :{
   "get" : {
        "operationId": "downLoadDATFileAsZip",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "name": "cycleId",
            "in": "path",
            "description": "Indicates the folder name from which file CDRrst.dat file is to be downloaded",
            "required" :true,
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "responses": {
          "200": {
            "description": "OK. Successfully processed the request",
            "schema": {
              "type": *********
            }
          }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

can you try to return,

```
@ApiOperation(value = "View a list of available Resource", response = Resource.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved list"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "You are not authorized to view the resource"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Accessing the resource you were trying to reach is forbidden"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "The resource you were trying to reach is not found")
})
@GetMapping("/downloadZip/{cycleId}")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> downLoadDATFileAsZip(@RequestParam(value ="cycleId", required = false)  String cycleId) {
       //generating zip file and returning as 
    Resource rscr = new Resource();
    return ResponseEntity.ok().body(rscr);
}
```

You can try,

```
  responses:
    '200':
      description: A list of users
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            properties:
              id:
                type: integer
                description: The user ID.
              username:
                type: string
                description: The user name.
```

Comment: Thanks for the update Ashish. Sorry, my query was not properly stated. I have made changes to it. Basically I am following bottom up approach and I want to generate the rest controller from the Swagger specification. I am not sure what should be the schema "type" of the response in Swagger specs such that it generates the api as I have mentioned i.e returning ResponseEntity<Response>

Comment: @NehaVashishth What are you using `SwaggerCodeGen` or `SwaggerEditor` ?

Comment: Ashish .. I'm using 'SwaggerCodeGen'

Comment: @Neha, what version is your openapi spec ? Instead of GetMapping i get RequestMapping in my api ..